Downloading and Opening PDF file in React Native
I'm trying to download a PDF file from my app when a button is clicked and open it immediately after the download completes. I'm using expo-file-system to save the downloaded file and I'm using expo-linking to trigger the opening of the file after it's downloaded for iOS device. I'm also using the expo-intent-launcher to trigger the opening of the file on an android device. This works perfectly for android but this doesn't work on iOS and I've been on this for hours. I'm unsure what I'm not doing right. My code snippets is shown below:
import * as FileSystem from "expo-file-system";
import * as Linking from "expo-linking";
import * as IntentLauncher from "expo-intent-launcher";
import { Button } from "react-native"

export default function PdfDocumentsScreen() {
   const { isAndroid } = useDevicePlatform();

   const downloadPDF = async () => {
    try {
      const uri =
        "https://${name}.s3.amazonaws.com/${bucket_name}/Certificate1.pdf";

      const fileUri = FileSystem.documentDirectory + "Certificate.pdf";

      const downloadObject = FileSystem.createDownloadResumable(uri, fileUri);

      const response = await downloadObject.downloadAsync();
      console.log(response);

      if (response?.status === 200) {
        openPDF(fileUri);
      } else {
        console.error("Failed to download the PDF");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error downloading the PDF: ", error);
    }
  };

 const openPDF = async (fileUri: string) => {
    try {
      const contentUri = await FileSystem.getContentUriAsync(fileUri);
      console.log("Content URI: ", contentUri);

      if (!isAndroid) {
        if (await Linking.canOpenURL(contentUri)) {
          Linking.openURL(contentUri);
        }
      } else {
        IntentLauncher.startActivityAsync("android.intent.action.VIEW", {
          data: contentUri,
          flags: 1,
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error opening the PDF: ", error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Button title="Download PDF" onPress={downloadPDF} />
  )
}


Update!!
I have long fixed this issue but I thought it would be great to post how I was able to work around the issue since the question has got no helpful answers.
The reason why this works on Android and not on iOS is because the expo-file-system FileSystem.getContentUriAsync() only works on Android as stipulated in the docs here: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/#filesystemgetcontenturiasyncfileuri
In order to get around this, I decided to use expo-sharing to trigger the opening of the PDF on iOS and expo-intent-launcher for triggering the opening on Android.
This is what the updated code looks like:
  const callback = (
    downloadProgress: {
      totalBytesExpectedToWrite: number;
      totalBytesWritten: number;
    },
    id: string
  ) => {
    const progress =
      downloadProgress.totalBytesWritten /
      downloadProgress.totalBytesExpectedToWrite;

    setDownloadProgress({
      progress,
      id: item._id!,
    });
  };

const downloadPDF = async () => {
    try {
      const uri = item.url;
      const fileUri = FileSystem.documentDirectory + `${fileName}.${extension}`;

      const downloadObject = FileSystem.createDownloadResumable(
        uri,
        fileUri,
        {},
        (downloadOption) => {
          callback(downloadOption, id);
        }
      );

      const response = await downloadObject.downloadAsync();

      if (response?.status === 200) {
        await openPDF(response.uri, response.mimeType);
      } else {
        setDownloadProgress({ progress: 0, id: "" });
        setDownloadError("Failed to download the PDF");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error downloading the PDF: ", error);
      if (error instanceof Error) {
        setDownloadError(error.message);
      } else {
        setDownloadError(`Error: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
      }
      setDownloadProgress({ progress: 0, id: "" });
    }
  };

  const openPDF = async (fileUri: string, mimeType: string | null) => {
    try {
      const contentUri = await FileSystem.getContentUriAsync(fileUri);

      if (!isAndroid) {
        Sharing.shareAsync(contentUri, { UTI: mimeType! });
      } else {
        IntentLauncher.startActivityAsync("android.intent.action.VIEW", {
          data: contentUri,
          flags: 1,
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof Error) {
        setDownloadError(error.message);
      } else {
        setDownloadError(`Error: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
      }
    }
  };


